# SLURM srun print log instance-wise

Tags: slurm

While using slurm on multi-node cluster,
I ran

```
srun -N 2 -C worker nvidia-smi
```

The output of this command is mangled/interleaved instead of in order.
Example output:

```
Tue Dec 15 22:37:55 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
Tue Dec 15 22:37:55 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:16.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    42W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:16.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    44W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:17.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   49C    P0    46W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:17.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    43W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected output:
Instance 1

```
Tue Dec 15 22:37:55 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:16.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    44W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:17.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    43W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Instance 2

```
Tue Dec 15 22:37:55 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:16.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    42W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:17.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   49C    P0    46W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--label` option to prefix each output line with the task number, and then use `sort` to group lines together:

```
 srun --label -N 2 -C worker nvidia-smi | sort -n
```

Comment: logically this makes sense. but somehow it doesn't really sort it as well as i want. the output still doesn't look the way it would if seen piece-wise[individually]. any thoughts?

Comment: gentle ping..any idea why the output is still not sorted properly

Comment: no, `sort` is supposed to sort. Maybe if you show the actual output that you get?